# Get Django User group in HTML

Tags: html, django

I am trying to get Django user's group in HTML for an if tag. This is what I tried:

```
{% ifequal user.groups.all.0 'ABC' %}
{% endif %}
```

But this is not working. What other way is there?

Comment: you mean logged in user ?

Comment: Yes. I want the logged in user

Comment: Then use `request.user.whatever ` ,

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name == 'ABC' %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or

```
{% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == 'ABC' %}{% endif %}
```

You have to access the current user object from the request context variable. For this, make sure that `django.template.context_processors.request` is in your template settings.

`request.user.groups.all.0` returns a Group model object, so you have to compare against the `name` field.

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work either. But if I am setting my <li> {{ user.groups.all.0 }}, that is showing me the group in the output. But an if statement doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I have tested this on Django 1.8 and is perfectly ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There seems to be some erratic behaviour on my side. It is working if used inside a completely unrelated if tag. Let me see what could be causing this.

Comment: This solution works, but it is sort of inefficient, since you get all of the user's groups from the database and loop over all of them in your template, while you actually only want to know if the user is a member of a given group. It is also not very reuseable.

Comment: My condition is always evaluating to false. Is there any common mistakes that could be causing it?

Comment: @RenéFleschenberg It depends if most users are member of one or few groups or not. Never such an operation in a template is efficient without proper context or tags. It is certainly way simpler than getting to define custom tags though. And it is reusable allright.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly if the current user is indeed not a member of the specific group?

Comment: Well, putting the {{ user.groups.all.0 }} in HTML gives the group name as output. I am using Django 1.5. Could that be an issue?

Comment: `{{ request.user }}` is the currently logged in user. Straight `{{ user }}` depends on your context. `{{ request.user.groups.0 }}` returns the same as in a view: `str(request.user.groups[0])` (if exists indeed) whereas `{{ request.user.groups.0.name }}` returns the same as request.user.groups[0].name`.

Comment: ``{{ user }}`` will be in your context if you put it there, or if ``django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`` is in your ``CONTEXT_PROCESSORS``. Anyway, I still *highly* recommend using a template tag. It's what they are there for, really.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to use a little Python here. For example, a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

And in your template:

```
{% if request.user|has_group:"ABC" %}
...
{% endif %}
```

(Source: http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/22/check-if-user-belongs-group-django-templates/)

But maybe you should actually use *permissions* here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

**Edit: Here is a more complete example of the custom template tag:**

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'yourapp',
    ...
]
```

Filesystem:

```
yourproject/
    manage.py
    yourproject/
        settings.py
        wsgi.py
        ...
    yourapp/
    __init__.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        yourapp_extras.py
    ...
```

yourapp_extras.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Template:

```
{% load yourapp_extras %}
{% if request.user|has_group:"ABC" %}
...
{% endif %}
```

To get a more thorough understanding of this, I highly recommend reading Django's excellent documentation.

Comment: Is there no way to sort this out in the HTML template itself? Doing it in views would be very complicated for my project

Comment: I can't get this to work for my project. I keep getting utils_extras not found even though it is in the correct directory

Comment: There are ways to do it in your templates, but I really recommend using a custom template tag. It is a lot easier than it sounds. Once you have done, you will not want to go back ;)

Comment: I updated the answer with a more complete example of a custom template tag. If you still get an error, please double-check that your templatetags module is in the right place, your names match and that you used ``register`` correctly. Also, your app needs to be in ``INSTALLED_APPS``.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>{{ user.groups.all.0 }}</h1>
{% if user.groups.all.0.name == 'Team2' %}
<h1>YES</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>NO</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Here, the user.groups.all.0 gives you the first group assigned to the user.

For eg. if the logged in user has groups assigned to him as- 'Team2', 'Programmer', 'Beginner'.
Then {{user.groups.all.0}} will print Team2.
I've used it to print and check the logged in user's group in html template.

OR

```
{% if request.user|has_group:"mygroup" %}
<h1>Has group mygroup</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Also works fine in django v1.11. This will check if the current user has 'mygroup' assigned to it or not.
However you'll need to add

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
return True if group in user.groups.all() else False
```

inside a group_check.py in below file structure

```
--app
    |templates
    |templatetags 
                 |-- group_check.py
```